# define variable with/without var prefix in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference define variable in **global scope** between

`var my_var;`

and

```
my_var;
```

Answer (score 1):

In global scope, there is no difference, unless you using it again: `var my_var;` will redeclare it, while `my_var;` will be simply useless expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference only when not in global context.

Ex1 (with var):

```
var x = 0; 
(function(){
  var x = 1; 
  alert('fx: '+ x);
})(); 
alert('gx: '+ x);

//fx: 1
//gx: 0
```

Ex2 (without var):

```
x = 0; 
(function(){
  x = 1; 
  alert('fx: '+ x);
})(); 
alert('gx: '+ x);

//fx: 1
//gx: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` is actually (re)declaring the variable in any current scope while second form is declaring it (globally?) unless it's been declared in a *containing* scope before. The second form is implicitly declaring, while first form is doing so explicitly.

Thus there is no difference in global scope, for it isn't contained in any other scope.